# Nomenclature for a graph such that each vertex has at least one adjacency.

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

**Background**

Consider an undirected graph without self loops, defined by the adjacency matrix $A = A^\top \in \{0,1\}^{n \times n}$, with $a_{v,v} = 0 ~\forall v \in \mathcal{V} = \{1, \ldots, n\}.$

Consider the following property:

$$\forall u \in \mathcal{V} ~\exists v \in \mathcal{V} \setminus \{u\} : a_{v,u} = 1.$$

Turning maths into words, each vertex of the graph has at least one **1-step** connection.

**Question**

Is there a name for a graph fulfilling this property?

Comment: "Turning maths into words" is not a fair description of the transformation between $\forall u \in \mathcal{V} ~\exists v \in \mathcal{V} \setminus \{u\} : a_{v,u} = 1$ and "each vertex of the graph has at least one connection". A better description would be "Writing some mathematical shorthand out in full." Something isn't more mathematical because you use symbols to represent it; often, that's just a way to make it harder to understand.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks a lot for you answer. Sorry, I did not get your point... Is it "stupid" to translate maths to english?

Comment: @MishaLavrov as far as I know, $v$ is connected to $u$ if $a_{vu}=1$. Differently (but the latter is a specific case of), $v$ has a path of length $p$ to $u$ if there exists a sequence like $a_{v,x_1} = 1, a_{x_1, x_2} = 1, \ldots, a_{x_{p-2},x_{p-1}}=1, a_{x_{p-1}, u} = 1$, provided that $u \neq x_q ~\forall q \in \{1, \ldots, p-1\}.$

Comment: It's not "stupid" to turn one into the other; I just don't want to encourage you to think of expressions like $\forall u \in \mathcal{V} ~\exists v \in \mathcal{V} \setminus \{u\} : a_{v,u} = 1$ as "the real math". The mathematics is in the idea; any way of expressing it is equally good, provided it is clear.

Comment: As for your second point - if someone said "$v$ is connected to $u$" that would probably be my *best guess* as to what they mean, but I wouldn't be sure, because terminology in graph theory varies. If someone said "$v$ is adjacent to $u$", I would be certain that they meant $a_{vu} = 1$. Therefore I think it's better to always say "adjacent".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no commonly-used special term for such a graph, but you can say that it's

- A graph with **minimum degree greater than 0** (which can be concisely written as $\delta(G) > 0$ if you are writing it many times), or
- A graph with **no isolated vertices**.

As another point of terminology, I would talk about "edges" rather than "connections" and say that a vertex is "adjacent" rather than "connected" to another vertex. The reason for this is that we also speak of a graph being **connected** if there is a path from every vertex to every other vertex, so saying "$v$ is connected to $w$" is ambiguous: do you mean that $v$ is adjacent to $w$, or that there is a path from $v$ to $w$?

(Relatedly, it's important to realize that having no isolated vertices does not guarantee that a graph is connected; this is a common mistake many beginners in graph theory make. It is possible to have no isolated vertices, but still have larger connected components with no edges between them.)

Comment: +1, both for the answer and for your attempt in comments to the question to explain to the OP that words are just as much "real mathematics" as complex notation - and often better for the reader.